# Adding a space to the data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure like the following:

```
declare @mySymbol as varchar(32)
DECLARE @RefGroupID AS VARCHAR(20)
declare @myJID as varchar(45)
declare Div_csr cursor for 
    select  distinct Symbol2, RefGroupID, jnl_id
    from @TDRows td
    WHERE TD_CompanyCode_AU = 'A'

open Div_csr
fetch next from Div_csr into @mySymbol, @RefGroupID, @myJID
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 begin
    SET @InfoMessage = @InfoMessage +CONVERT(varchar(30),getdate(), 120)+ ' ' + @SPname 
        + ': RefGroupID:'+ convert(varchar(20),@RefGroupID,101) 
        + ' Sym: ' + @mySymbol 
        + ' JID: ' + @myJID 
        + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
    fetch next from Div_csr into @mySymbol, @RefGroupID, @myJID

end
close Div_csr
deallocate Div_csr
```

`@mySymbol` is the data I want to modified.

For example; `@mySymbol` is `BXP PRB`. You can see there is a space between `BXP` and `PRB`. I want to this space also show in the comment that was created using the stored procedure.

Right now, the commment's `Sym:` is parsed by data `@mySymbol`. But it does not have space now. I do not know why.. .

The comment looks like this:

> "DIV2PAY  Record receipt from CSH RecordDt=08/04/2017 Intended PayDt= 08/15/2017 Sym=BXPPRB Qty=-100 CashRate=0.328125 Kind= Cash Dividend RowID= 127278 CAEventID= 105226767
>   
> ".

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: the cause must be somewhere further up the line. I guess it is already wrong in the `@TDRows` table. Can you verify, and/or show how that table is filled?

Comment: also, if we assume that "comment" is `@InfoMessage`, then the rest of the sample you show is not in line with what the procedure does: it uses colons : to separate names from values, and your sample uses = for the same. Does not look like it could be output from that procedure at all.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something here... your code and the generated comment aren't lining up...

Comment: You really should not be using a cursor here. They are horribly inefficient and should only be used for a few administrative and other specialized tasks.

Comment: I feel like you are looking at the wrong code

Comment: Thanks guys, i think i probably find the wrong code... is varchar() type does not have the space? And is there any suggestions what is the problem if the data has spcace, but when i put it into the comment, it does not have space?

Comment: @Rachel `VARCHAR` supports spaces.

Comment: If you simply want to inject a space into the 4th character position, you can use the STUFF function... STUFF(@mySymbol, 4, 0, ' ')